# ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy

Tags: ios, app-store, plist, appstore-approval, privacy-policy

Why am I all of a suddent getting this on successful builds with Apple?

> Although submission for App Store review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for App Store review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Test” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

Comment: It looks like a lot of people are seeing this (I just did). It looks like a privacy file of some sort is required, I am still working through the details

e.g.
https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow-issues/issues/2527

Comment: React Native uses `.plist` files the same way any iOS app does.  It's just that the app code/logic is Javascript.  This is then bundled up into a normal `.ipa` (or `.aab`/`.apk` for Android), along with all the RN wrapper magic.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? When you validate your app? Submit it to App Store Connect? I am trying to validate some things and I would expect to get notified about this, but I am not seeing it anywhere.

Comment: I tried the scan but it doesn't seem to show any privacy stuff @jki

Comment: Do you have to send the app for review in order to check if the problem resolved ( after adding the PrivacyInfo file)? I remember that this warnings/errors used to show in the app distribution process (the ipa upload process to App Store)

Comment: @RobinMacharg How did you add these policies for react native?

Comment: @HamzaKashif, it's on my list of things to do.  I'll feedback when I have.  I imagine it's just a case of following [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files) in Xcode.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This is all documented in the Apple's website. Here are the steps:

- Create a privacy manifest file for your app:

> To add the privacy manifest to your app or third-party SDK in Xcode, follow these steps:
> Choose File > New File.
>
> Scroll down to the Resource section, and select App Privacy File type.
>
> Click Next.
>
> Check your app or third-party SDK’s target in the Targets list.
>
> Click Create.
>
> By default, the file is named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy; this is the
> required file name for bundled privacy manifests.

- At the top level of this property list file, add the following key to the dictionary:

  `NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes`
- Basically, the keys that you need to add have been mentioned in the Apple's email: `... you must include a NSPrivacy....` , in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api) search for each of the keys mentioned in your email starting with `NSPrivacy...` and see what the accepted reason codes are related to your own app and add it.

You should have one `item` for each `NSPrivacy...` key under the `NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes`, which each of them has only one `Privacy Accessed API Type` which is the key name and one `Privacy Accessed API Reasons` which can include one or more reason codes.

And Do not forget to select target for **PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy** file.

[image]
Your privacy manifest file will look like something like this in the end:

[image: Privacy manifest file after adding keys]

References:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files#4284009

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

Comment: I think the problem is not your app itself, are the 3rd party frameworks, they also need to have these files. I'ts written in the apple docs.

```Your app or third-party SDK must declare one or more approved reasons that accurately reflect your use of each of these APIs and the data derived from their use.
```

Comment: After doing this I kept getting the error, I solved it by tying the privacy info file to the app (in the inspector panel).

Comment: Please remember to designate "Target of your app" for the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file.

Comment: Do we need to update all the SDKs or only those mentioned in [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/)? What if some SDKs are not maintained anymore?

Comment: @chengsam Updating the ones mentioned in the doc should work.

Comment: This worked for me, but whenever I distribute my app, I always get these policies are missing email from apple. However, my build gets approved

Comment: @HamzaKashif There can be two reasons:
1. You haven't selected your app targets in the inspector panel for the privacy file (Please refer to the first image in the answer)
2. Please read the new email once again, the API keys mentioned in the new email might have changed and you might not have included those in your privacy file yet. 
After checking these two and making the necessary changes, you can submit a new build.

Comment: They will stop approving after May 1, 2024. Check off your target in the "Target Membership" box in the inspector panel when your privacy manifest file is selected. I wish the Apple Documentation had been clearer when it said "You need to add the privacy manifest file to your target’s resources"

Comment: @MahdiehShavandi We are using a bunch of SDKs which have not been updated for quite a long time. It may take a lot of time and testing to upgrade all the SDKs just for the privacy manifest. Do you know if an app level privacy manifest is enough, provided that the file includes all the reasons Apple warns?

Comment: @chengsam In my case, it even worked without updating the SDKs. So, I think that should be fine for now.

Answer (score 39):

I was getting similar warnings after my upload. Seems there is still quite some time to resolve it (before May 1, 2024). I added the following keys to the app target's Privacy manifest (`PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy`), based on [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api) regarding the matter.

```
<key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>C617.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>CA92.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

[image: It will look like this in the editor]

The Privacy Manifest file can be created from Xcode. Create a new file, search and select App Privacy as a file type, and select the concerning targets (those targets are mentioned in these warnings you got after uploading).
Details on how to edit the Privacy Manifest is documented in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files).

And also more on it in this [WWDC 2023 video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10060).

Comment: So this worked for you? You didnt need this PrivacyInfo.cxprivacy file like in another answer?

Comment: I would not work. I add these in my info.plist and nothing happen.

Comment: Apple's docs don't say you can add these strings to your Info.plist file. I'd go down the PrivacyInfo.cxprivacy file route.

Comment: I don't think you can place these keys in your Info.plist file.. Apple docs suggest creating a new Privacy file and specifically naming it PrivacyInfo.cxprivacy:
"By default, the file is named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy; this is the required file name for bundled privacy manifests."

Comment: Yes, you're so right. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks, @GusThrelfall, the file needs to be named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy.

Answer (score 17):

For flutter devs it's fine to create a new App Privacy file in xcode (%YOUR_FLUTTER_PROJECT%/ios/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy) and configure the keys and reasons. e.g:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
      <array>
          <dict>
              <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
              <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
              <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
              <array>
                  <string>E174.1</string>
              </array>
          </dict>
          <dict>
              <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
              <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
              <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
              <array>
                  <string>CA92.1</string>
              </array>
          </dict>
      </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

[image]

UPDATE: please not just copy w/o verifying your own API usage. Possible reasons are listed here:

[Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api)

Comment: Of course each developer should check and verify the correct answer for each, not just cut and paste...

Comment: @jcaron I should probably make it more clear :) thank you

Comment: for some reason, this did not work for me, I'm still getting the warning.

Comment: @FarhanFida can you do one test, by adding your information to the Info.plist as well? It seems that in some cases adding it to the Info.plist helped, but could not verify yet.

Answer (score 13):

Starting in fall 2023, you will receive an email when uploading apps that use Apple's essential API to App Store Connect. If the reason for using the API is not explained in the app's PrivacyInfo file, the app will not pass from May 2024.

You can see what APIs are there and what are the reasons for the approval.
:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

Also there's this video about it - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060

**[how to use?]**

1.you have to add PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
[image]

2.In the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file, you can define what data the SDK collects, where it is used for connection, and whether it is used for tracking.
[image]￼

Comment: No plist entries?

Comment: @MikeFlynn yes just you have to add App Privacy File(.xcpricacy)

Answer (score 10):

Received the same notification from Apple:
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “ ” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime. While no action is required at this time...

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “ ” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required at this time...

Added PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file as in video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060 with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                  <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>35F9.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**And don't forget to set Target Membership for this file to your main bundle.** Otherwise you will get the same result.

After this I didn't get warning from Apple.

P.S. One more important note. If extensions are used in the project, the email from Apple will probably include these extensions as well. In this case, the separate PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files with the necessary reasons must be added to the specified extensions as well. Accordingly, you must set the Target Membership for PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy depending on the extension required.

Comment: Of course each developer should check and verify the correct answer for each, not just cut and paste...

Comment: Thanks for the target membership warning, that's what I was missing. Just a note for others: the generated privacy report PDF is identical for me whether target membership is checked or not, but checking it fixed the app store warning.

Answer (score 8):

**I AM USE THIS IS FULL CODE APPLE ERROR MESSAGE REMOVED 100% WORKING  **

> To add the privacy manifest to your app or third-party SDK in Xcode, follow these steps:

Choose File > New File.

Scroll down to the Resource section, and select App Privacy File type.

Click Next.

Check your app or third-party SDK’s target in the Targets list.

Click Create.

By default, the file is named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy; this is the required file name for bundled privacy manifests.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>35F9.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>C617.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>85F4.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: While this answer describes how to add privacy manifest, you should not declare APIs that you don't use, only ones that you (or 3rd party SDKs included in your app) use.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful! I thought I had to add it to the Info.plist, but that doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @jki did you find anywhere the confirmation that devs should also add things used by 3rd party SDKs?

Comment: Thankyou. After about 7 failed attempts using other's answers, this actually works. Not only do you need PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy but also these are the accepted reasons for the API Types that Apple will accept. This should be the accepted answer. Obviously you should only include the APIs that your app uses. This should be the accepted answer and right at the top of this page.

Comment: should we also write in our privacy manifest APIs using by 3rd party sdks, or its enough to update sdks so they will write their API usage in their manifest info?

Comment: I am still getting the same response from apple, even though I added privacy file.
Any idea what to do?

Comment: @HamzaKashif Please share screenshot apple message so we are helping

Comment: @HamzaKashif you have to set Target Membership for this file to your main bundle or extension (depend on Apple's email)

Answer (score 6):

Explanation: The ITMS-91053 errors you received indicate that your app's code specifically references APIs within the mentioned categories. This isn't a generic template that all apps must fill out; rather, it's a notification based on a scan of your app's binary by Apple's review process, which identified that your app uses these specific APIs. **Starting May 1, 2024**, Apple requires developers to declare the use of such APIs in their app's

Just in case you're looking for an example, my **PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy** Source Code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!--
PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
SwiftyGaming

Created by Ndriqim Haxhaj on 3/21/24.
Copyright (c) 2024 ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
-->
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>CA92.1</string>
                    <string>C56D.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>35F9.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>E174.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
                <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                <array>
                    <string>DDA9.1</string>
                    <string>0A2A.1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The **PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy** must be created this way:
[image]

Full article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files

Mine is located near **Info.plist** (don't mix these two) [image]

All the reasons used above (CA92.1, C56D.1, ...) are taken from official documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

Here is a final representation of **PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy** as Property List:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apple is sending this email because your application or the 3rd party SDK used by your application is using any of the APIs that require its reason to use.

You can check the api and their reasons from the following links.

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

A list of third parties can be found

- https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/

**What you have to do is**

- Add the privacyinfo.xcprivacy file from xcode
- Update the SDK version to a version that has privacyinfo support.

Answer (score -5):

add the following keys to my Info.plist

```
<key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDomains</key>
  <array/>
  <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict/>
  </array>
  <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>C617.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>35F9.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>7D9E.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>CA92.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Comment: Of course each developer should check and verify the correct answer for each, not just cut and paste...

Comment: This is not what Apple's documentation says to do. Instead you need to create a privacy manifest file. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files

Answer (score -8):

[image]
After add PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy in you target past the code like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>We check whether there is sufficient disk space to write files or crop image</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>We are using this API to store data in local storage.</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>We are getting file to update user profile pick.</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>We are using this API to get current date of system.</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This is not correct. You need to use pre-defined reasons.