# ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration in Flutter Project

Tags: ios, flutter, build, app-store-connect

We noticed one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for the following app:

```
Version 1.0.30
Build 2
Although submission for App Store review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for App Store review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
```

Apple Developer Relations

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163859/itms-91053-missing-api-declaration-privacy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add one of the previously listed reasons (just the code) available on Xcode in your PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file, like the ones below, also you can check all the options in this link:

[Describing use of required reason API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>E174.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Apple accepts your app after adding this ..?

Comment: Is this solution working on React native iOS?

Comment: @AhsanKhan yes, it was accepted without any problems. I already did this in 4 different apps.

Comment: @M.Kalidass I can't confirm because I don't use React Native, but I believe the principle is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Create new privacy file like - PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy and past the code like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!--
   PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
   Runner

   Created by chirag sondagar on 21/03/24.
   Copyright (c) 2024 . All rights reserved.
-->

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeOtherDataTypes</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeCoarseLocation</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePhotosorVideos</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>C617.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>E174.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
                    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
                    <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
                    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>8FFB.1</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I created a file in the ios folder and then created the file PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
The App Store sent me a message that it was not successful

Comment: I tried this solution and didn't work. Still got the warning message from App Store Connect about NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults

Answer (score 1):

watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6IvImk66m8

create file called: PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update Info.plist**

Once you know which APIs are causing the issue, you need to add the necessary keys to your ***Info.plist*** file with a description of why your app needs these permissions. The ***Info.plist*** file is located in the ***ios/Runner*** folder of your Flutter project.

For example, if the issue is related to the camera, you would add the following entry -

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera to take photos.</string>
```