# Missing an expected key: 'NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got the issue in my Policies I don't know why? Even I follow all Instruction that apple provide on their [official Page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.). But could not find any solution here.

I also followed [ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163859/itms-91053-missing-api-declaration-privacy) on StackOverflow

Here is my PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file

[image]

I download the Privacy Report I shows me that error
[image]

Comment: The error message is very clear about what you should do - add a `'NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes'` key to your privacy manifest. Did you try doing that?

Comment: Yes I add the Key " <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>" It still give me same error.

Comment: Perhaps the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file is missing from a third-party framework or library that's included in your project?  I got an error message that NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes is missing from "MyApp.app/Frameworks/PSPDFKit.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy".  That library has not yet been updated with this privacy info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the attached photo, your `NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes` was empty. You need to provide at least one data type, which is listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_data_use_in_privacy_manifests). i.e, You're collecting user email for advertising purpose, it's should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeEmailAddress</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeDeveloperAdvertising</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image]