# ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - ReactNative

Tags: react-native

Although submission for TestFlight review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for TestFlight review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “My app” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “My app” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

Why is this warning appearing even though I haven't made any changes to the native code?"

Is it possible not to initialize PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163859/itms-91053-missing-api-declaration-privacy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's difficult to describe, there's a really good explanation in this YouTube video.

https://youtu.be/T6IvImk66m8?si=N1D0IA2Irx9-_CyX

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api) in the warning you receive

> Starting May 1, 2024, apps that don’t describe their use of required reason API in their privacy manifest file aren’t accepted by App Store Connect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a requirement recently added by Apple. Starting May 1st, 2024 some 3rd party SDKs are required to add a privacy manifest file. In theory sometime before May 1st 2024, all of the 3rd party SDKs listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/) should update their packages to include the required file. As a developer using those packages the only thing you should need to do is keep whichever of those packages you are using up to date. As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_data_use_in_privacy_manifests) Apple has stated that you as a developer do not need to do anything in your app's privacy manifest file, it should all be taken care of by the 3rd party SDKs. Whether or not they actually succeed in updating their packages before May 1st remains to be seen.