# Apple Complains About Missing API Declaration In Titanium App

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile

I received an email from Apple regarding my app written using Titanium SDK. It says:

> Although submission for App Store review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for App Store review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the "APP_NAME" file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
>
> ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the "APP_NAME" file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

I saw an answer for this issue on another web page, but they are using XCode to make the required files, and I am using Titanium to write and build my app.

[ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163859/itms-91053-missing-api-declaration-privacy)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163859/itms-91053-missing-api-declaration-privacy)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Titanium SDK PR that will take care of it for the next release and has some more infos: https://github.com/tidev/titanium-sdk/pull/14007

[Some docs](https://github.com/tidev/titanium-docs/blob/6bb8782107473399fd07ce8ff60c2ec8a0b7b3d5/docs/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_How-tos/Adhere_to_the_iOS17_Privacy_Requirements.md) how to fix it in the current release and a [preview of that PrivacyInfo file](https://github.com/tidev/titanium-docs/blob/6bb8782107473399fd07ce8ff60c2ec8a0b7b3d5/docs/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_How-tos/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy). Both of those are also work-in-progress and can be tracked in [this titanium-docs PR](https://github.com/tidev/titanium-docs/pull/215).

edit: PR got merged :) It's now in the docs https://titaniumsdk.com/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_How-tos/Adhere_to_the_iOS17_Privacy_Requirements.html